# associative arrays and array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

`print_r($element_attrs);` returns the following arrays which are gathered from an xml file.

```
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms Likely ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Chance Thunderstorms ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Partly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Partly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Rain Fog/Mist ) 
Array ( )
```

Right now they are 16 separate associative arrays in which all the keys are the same except for the last one that's blank for some reason.  I'd like to merge these separate arrays into one big array using `array_merge()` or another function so that I can return the second to last value that says "Rain Fog/Mist"

Right now when I do `print_r(array_merge($element_attrs));` I get:

```
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms Likely ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Chance Thunderstorms ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Partly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Partly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Rain Fog/Mist ) 
Array ( )
```

Comment: Do you need any of the other arrays, or just the second to last?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its a little messy but I ended up using css to make all of them except the last one of each group invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of all of the values of $element_attrs arrays this should work.

```
function getLastWeatherSummary($arr){
    $ret = array();
    foreach($arr as $summary){
       if(array_key_exists("WEATHER-SUMMARY", $summary)){
          $ret[] = $summary["WEATHER-SUMMARY"];
       }
    }
    // if you want the whole array 
    // return $ret

    // if you only care about the last one
    return array_pop($ret);
}
```

If you only care about the last one when you are assigning each of the $element_attrs values you can do

```
// loop through elements and set the value of $element_attrs
if (array_key_exists("WEATHER-SUMMARY", $element_attrs)){ 
   $last_summary = $element_attrs["WEATHER-SUMMARY"];
}
```

After the loop you should end up with a variable named $last_summary that contains the last defined value.

Comment: part of the problem is that I am having trouble creating one array that holds all the values.  Its 16 separate arrays that I'd like to merge so that I can isolate certain values.

Comment: the second one works but still returns all arrays and values(including the blank one).  I'm still having trouble implementing the first one. Do I need to have anything else going besides what you've put there?  Do I need to change one of your variables for $element_attr?

Comment: I imagine you have some sort of foreach in which you are getting each of the values for $element_attrs, to collect everything up in to an array you just need to (before you enter the loop) create an array `$arr = array();` and then in the loop after you assign the $element_attrs just call `$arr[] = $element_attrs`.  That array is what should be passed into the getLastWeatherSummary call.

Comment: When I try a foreach() loop, it treats each array separately as it cycles through instead of cycling through all the arrays.  For example, if I created a loop that put a number in front of each array's values before finishing, each value would get a number one or zero (whichever I designated as a starting index).  If I create an array of numbers for it to cycle through as it cycles through the weather arrays, it puts all 16 numbers in front of each weather value.  Isn't that strange?!

Comment: if the $element_attrs is an array that contains a single array element then the getLastWeatherSummary should work if you change $summary into $summary[0] in foreach in the function.

Comment: actually looking at your original post again I think you should be able to pass the $element_attrs into the function it was defined in my answer.

Comment: so I would replace $summary with $element_attrs? and you think it should work?

Comment: when you call the function just pass in the $element_attrs don't change the anything in the function. That is assuming the dump in the question above is from a single var_dump call.

Comment: when I var_dump, it looks like this `array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(13) "Thunderstorms" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(13) "Thunderstorms" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(20) "Chance Thunderstorms" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(13) "Mostly Cloudy" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(12) "Mostly Sunny" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(12) "Mostly Clear" } array(1) { ["WEATHER-SUMMARY"]=> string(5) "Sunny" }`

Comment: I don't think they're from a single var_dump call....I believe it runs the var_dump call individually for each array

Answer (score 0):

#### Example Data:

```
$array = array(
    array('WEATHER-SUMMARY' => 'Thunderstorms'),
    array('WEATHER-SUMMARY' => 'Thunderstorms Likely'),
    array('WEATHER-SUMMARY' => 'Chance Thunderstorms'),
    array('WEATHER-SUMMARY' => 'Mostly Cloudy'),
    array('WEATHER-SUMMARY' => 'Mostly Sunny'),
    array() 
);
```

#### Using `array_filter()` and `array_map()`:

```
$flatArray = array_filter(array_map(function($a) {
    if (!empty($a['WEATHER-SUMMARY'])) {
        return $a['WEATHER-SUMMARY'];
    }
}, $array));
```

#### Using a `foreach()` loop:

```
$flatArray = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if (!empty($a['WEATHER-SUMMARY'])) {
        $flatArray[] = $a['WEATHER-SUMMARY'];
    }
}
```

Then, you can just use `array_pop()` to get the last array entry:

```
echo array_pop($flatArray); // 'Mostly Sunny'
```

Comment: The first one returns something but not what I was looking for.  $var returns all array values (even the blank one).  I can't get the second one to work. Do I need to change one of your variables to my array variable $element_attrs?

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to collect up all of the different values of $element_attrs.  So before you enter into the loop that assigns the values create an empty array.

```
$weatherSummaries = array();
```

while in the loop that cycles over the elements right after to assign the $element_attrs variable add the values associated with the WEATHER-SUMMARY key of the $element_attrs to the weatherSummaries array (only if it's not null)

```
if (array_key_exists("WEATHER-SUMMARY", $element_attrs)){
    $weatherSummaries[] =  $element_attrs["WEATHER-SUMMARY"];
}
```

Now after the loop exists you should have a single array ($weatherSummaries) that contains the WEATHER-SUMMARY element of each of the arrays.

You can get at the last one by referencing

```
$weatherSummaries[count($weatherSummaries) -1)];
```